# how i can connect my java program to a particular webpage

Tags: java, netbeans

i want to run my java program in netbeans IDE using web page. first it sends the content of jtextarea to webpage's textarea then perform some action over that data and then return the result back to jtextarea. i dont know how it is to be done? 
please help me?
thx.

Comment: *"please help me?"*  Please find your shift key, and use it at least at the start of every sentence.  Also note that your title is a question, and should have a question mark, while the statement I quoted is not a question but a request, and should *not* have a question mark.

Comment: @Andrew - did you decide to give up coffee today? :)

Comment: @pap  I usually just edit them without comment.  But I looked at that mess & realized I could comment with less effort.  Thanks for your interest. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing it from scratch,

why not to have *webservices* to perform the things for you and consume it from your application.

if it is third party web site you are trying to use then you can use `HTTPURLConnection` to make GET POST